# Python3: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x

master_frame["primary_sector"]=master_frame["category_list"].str.split("|").apply(lambda x: x[0])

I have a column- "category_list" which is a combination of names delimited by "|". I have to take the first name from that column and create a new column- "primary_sector".

I am running the above code but it is giving me this error: "float" object not subscriptable.
I don't understand, why it is showing an error. Am I being clear enough?

Comment: `master_frame["category_list"].str.split("|").str[0]`

Comment: Also, please add the full error trace, and a sample of your dataframe so that we can be sure that this is the line that's actually causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @PMende, it worked.
But just out of curiosity, what was wrong with my code?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution works on a dataframe like you describe:

```
master_frame = pd.DataFrame(['hello|world', 'hello|world'], columns=['category_list'])
master_frame["primary_sector"] = master_frame["category_list"].str.split("|").apply(lambda x: x[0])

master_frame

    category_list   primary_sector
0   hello|world     hello
1   hello|world     hello
```

So probably the error is in the dataframe that you are using or your categories.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and apologies for sharing incomplete information. I figured that the my code was not working because of null values in the column.

Comment: No worries, accept the answer if it solved your question.